# What does this c# code do (list)?

Tags: c#

I don't understand the syntax.

```
public List<Person> People { get { return _people; } }
```

Comment: What part of the syntax do you not understand? The List<Person> part or the Getter portion?

Answer (score 4):

What you have is a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

- `public` this is the [accessibility of the property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)
- `List<Person>` the is the [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) returned by the property
- `People` the name given to the property
- `get { return _person; }` this [defines the getter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69wcs43.aspx) for the property, which in this case will return the value of `_person`, defined elsewhere in the type.

---

You would access the value of this property like this

```
List<Person> listOfPeople = parentType.People;
```

Because only the `get` accessor is supplied (i.e. there is no `set` accessor), the following will throw a compile time exception:

```
parentType.People = anotherListOfPeople;
```

---

Because the type exposes `List<People>`, which inherits from [the `IList<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use the methods defined in it; e.g. if you wanted to add a `Person` you would do it like so:

```
parentType.People.Add(newPerson);
```

Answer (score 3):

It defines a property of type `List<Person>`.

Since there is no `set` part of the property, it only allows getting the values but not setting them. The value it returns in this case is the value of `_people`. This is defined somewhere else, not in the code you provided.

Read more about properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: What does return _people do?

Comment: Sorry @Scartag, I've sort of hijacked your answer. Started as a small edit :P

Comment: @JamesWebster No problem .. you've made the answer much better than i intended to :)